# Static Library Linking Issue "Undefined symbols" for symbols that are defined

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, static-libraries

I am using Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) to compile. It's about 1200 files, but I have used them before. I go and compile them all, no problems. Then I make my static library (`ar rcs libblib.a *.o`), no problems. So when I try to use my brand new library, I have my problem.

```
gcc main.c  -L. -lblib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_N_method", referenced from:
      _main in main-7fc584.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

But, I know this is defined. I check to see that the file is included (`ar -t libblib.a | grep N_METHOD.o`) and it is in there. Check the source file, and there is the method, exactly named as it is in the header file. What is the problem I am having here? I am at a complete loss and I am hoping I am missing something simple.

I did `nm -g N_METHOD.o` and got back:

```
0000000000000000 T __Z8N_methodP6stacks
```

Comment: Is the library written in C or C++? If it's C++, the names will be mangled.

Comment: @Barmar: C does not support _methods_, Occam's razor tells me this is C++ ;-)

Comment: It is C. I am just using N_method as a place holder.

Comment: GCC uses --static to link static libraries

Comment: Have you checked that `N_METHOD.o` is a 64-bit object file (or a fat object file with both 32-bit and 64-bit code in it)?  If it is a 32-bit object file, then it is no use for a 64-bit program.  However, that's a little unlikely; you have to go out of your way to create a 32-bit object file on Mac.  Have you run `nm -g N_METHOD.o` to see whether `_N_method` is defined in the object file?  Also, you seem to be linking with `libblib.a` (specifying `-lblib`), but you are checking in `libnlib.a`, which is nominally wholly unrelated.  Is that a problem with the question or with your checking?

Comment: Sorry, the nlib thing was a typo. I did nm -g on N_METHOD.o and got back: 0000000000000000 T __Z8N_methodP6stacks

Comment: Don't compile C code with a C++ compiler.  Or don't try to compile C++ code with a C compiler.  The mangled name is for C++.  Maybe you simply need to link with `g++` instead of `gcc`?  They are different languages — this is the property of 'type-safe linkage' that is characteristic of C++ and completely unknown to C.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

Based on the question content, I asked:

- Have you checked that `N_METHOD.o` is a 64-bit object file (or a fat object file with both 32-bit and 64-bit code in it)? If it is a 32-bit object file, then it is no use for a 64-bit program. However, that's a little unlikely; you have to go out of your way to create a 32-bit object file on Mac.
- Have you run `nm -g N_METHOD.o` to see whether `_N_method` is defined in the object file?

> I did `nm -g N_METHOD.o` and got back:
>
> ```
> 0000000000000000 T __Z8N_methodP6stacks
> ```

Don't compile C code with a C++ compiler. Or don't try to compile C++ code with a C compiler. The mangled name (`__Z8N_methodP6stacks`) is for C++. Maybe you simply need to link with `g++` instead of `gcc`? They are different languages — this is the property of 'type-safe linkage' that is characteristic of C++ and completely unknown to C.

First step — compile and link with:

```
g++ main.c -L. -lblib
```

Assuming that the source is in the C++ subset of C (or C subset of C++), then the chances are that should work.  At least, if the code contains `N_Method(&xyz)` where `xyz` is a variable of type `stacks`, then there's a chance it will call `__Z8N_methodP6stacks`.

The following code:

```
typedef struct stacks stacks;
extern int N_method(stacks*);

extern int relay(stacks *r);

int relay(stacks *r) { return N_method(r); }
```

compiles with a C++ compiler to produce the `nm -g` output:

```
0000000000000000 T __Z5relayP6stacks
                 U __Z8N_methodP6stacks
```

It also compiles with a C compiler to produce the `nm -g` output:

```
0000000000000038 s EH_frame1
                 U _N_method
0000000000000000 T _relay
```